# How to email and ask the recruiter about the progress/situation of my job application?

Tags: hiring-process, email, follow-up

Last week I applied for a job & sent my CV & other details to the recruiter. Then they sent me back another form to fill which contained some competency type questions. I filled out the form and sent it to them the same day and received a email back thanking me for sending it through and that they'll send it to their head office.

Throughout this process I have been in contact with only one person.

My question is how should I word my email to that person to ask about the progress of my application? I don't want to sound too annoying, please note that I have NOT sent an email to them asking about progress before.

Im a bit on edge waiting for the call/email.

Comment: I don't agree on the duplicate but this question *is* off-topic here: we're not a writing service and "how do I ask for an update?" is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

I would just keep it very short as a reply to their last email.

"Hello X, hope you are well, I'm just following up on my application. Has there been any progress?
Regards
Y"

Or something similar